# match leading dots in bash if using regex

Tags: regex, bash

Say I want to match the leading dot in a string ".a"

So I type

> [[ ".a" =~ ^\. ]] && echo "ha"

ha

> [[ "a" =~ ^\. ]] && echo "ha"

ha

Why am I getting the same result here?

Comment: After testing your 2 commands, the 2nd one does not output `ha`.

Comment: I agree with jfgagne.  That does work on a modern version of bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's because bash tries to treat "." as a \ character, like \n \r etc.

In order to tell \ & . as 2 separate characters, try

```
[[ "a" =~ ^\\. ]] && echo ha
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dot it has meaning beyond just a period  - it is a metacharacter in regex.

```
 [[ "a" =~ ^\. ]] && echo "ha"
```

Make the change in the other example as well.

Check your bash version - you need 4.0 or higher I believe.

Comment: Okay... actually I did. sorry I did not notice,  It was when I typed in here the backslash '\' was dropped for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

There's some compatibility issues with `=~` between `Bash` versions after `3.0`. The safest way to use `=~` in Bash is to put the RE pattern in a var:

```
$ pat='^\.foo'
$ [[ .foo =~ $pat ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ foo =~ $pat ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
$
```

For more details, see [E14 on the Bash FAQ page](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ).